# How to check if pagination links will be shown in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using paginate for my pagination and I want to add custom markup for the `$items->links()` in Blade like this:

```
<div class="pagination-wrapper">
    {{ $items->links() }}
</div>
```

How do I check if the pagination links will be shown so that I won't print out an empty pagination-wrapper?

Comment: Did you just ask and reply to yourself within a minute? LOL.

Comment: @ChinLeung I did post it at the same time. It may help others who may find it useful. haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On **Laravel 5 or above** there is even better and Laravel native way to check if pagination links will be shown in laravel blade.

```php
@if ($items->hasPages())
    <div class="pagination-wrapper">
         {{ $items->links() }}
    </div>
@endif
```

[From Laravel API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html)

```
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Method        |                            Description                            |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $results->hasPages() | Determine if there are enough items to split into multiple pages. |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This the right answer now that the current Laravel version has the proper method for it

Answer (score 6):

I found out that you can access the total number of items and the items per page displayed for pagination. After that, it's easy to check if there is only one page - meaning there will be no pagination links to be shown.

```
@if ($items->total() > $items->perPage())
    <div class="pagination-wrapper">
         {{ $items->links() }}
    </div>
@endif
```